# Trying to save a file but getting "Parent directory of file does not exist" even after trying to create dir

Tags: android

I'm trying to save an image to my sdcard but running into the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Parent directory of file does not exist: /sdcard/skdyImages/a46e2e08-9154-4fe7-96e8-2af0a7a92867.jpg
```

I do have the permissions in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is my code:

```
String newName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            Bitmap bmp = ImageLoader.getInstance().getBitmap(e.getUrl());
            File file = new File("/sdcard/skdyImages", newName + ".jpg");
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
// Automatically creates folder on sdcard called /Android/data/<package>/files
// if it doesn't exist
File ImageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath());

BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(ImageDir + "/" + newName + ".jpg"));
```

Comment: I think that worked since I can see that the cache size for the application goes up and I don't get that error anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Use something like Astro to examine /mnt/sdcard/Android/data and you should see a folder with your package name. Note: this folder is automatically deleted by the App Manager if you uninstall your app. You might also want to look at android.os.Environment for other get...() methods for returning public directories which aren't deleted if your app is uninstalled.